# Deserialize JSON array to a strongly typed model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
  {}: "request": 
      {
        "result": "1",
        "errorId": "",
        "errorMessage": ""
      }
}
```

How can i deserialize this to a strongly typed object? how does the object need to be built?

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public string errorId { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Model 
{
    public List<RequestModel> request { get; set; }
}

var result = jObjectModel.toObject<Model>();
```

But this is throwing an error.

Comment: It's not valid JSON. On line two, remove the additional `{}:` before the `"request"` property.

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON. I don't think `{ {}: "request":  { ` makes any sense. You need another pair of curly braces (opening right before `"request"`. I think... Or, @kieron's suggestion (which would make it more C# friendly). As it is, I don't think it will parse

Answer (score 1):

You json for Model should look like this

```
{
    "request": [
        {
            "result": "One",
            "errorId": "Error One",
            "errorMessage": "Error One Message"
        },
        {
            "result": "Two",
            "errorId": "Error Two",
            "errorMessage": "Error Two Message"
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure where jObjectModel package comes from, but using Newtonsoft JSON the syntax is

```
Model tst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```

I have put an example at [RexTester](https://rextester.com/PZMW79213)